# How to find the index of the max value from the array ,smaller or equal to the input

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

The problem is somewhat like,to find the maximum reachable point in the path.Lets say we have an array of 6 elements. Assuming the array is sorted. Value of first element of the array is zero.
Considering the elements of the array are {'0','200',' 375', '550', '750','950'}.
Let say we have to input a value between 0 and 950. We have to return the index of the max value from the array smaller or equal to the input value. 
I am trying to get this done using while loop but i am stuck!!!
Here is my code

```
  void  compute_min_refills(int value, int n, vector<int>  stops) {
     int currentrefill=0,num=0,lastrefill=0;
 lastrefill = currentrefill;
    while(currentposition <= n && stops[currentposition + 1] - stops[lastposition] < Value){ 
        currentposition = currentposition + 1;
    }
    cout<<currentposition<<' ';

}
```

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Can you also specify what is n ? You are also comparing equal to n, `currentposition <= n`, if n is length of array then we don't compare with n as the last element is n-1

Comment: Lets say ,if i have a value 400 then the output should be 2 since 375 is lesser than 400... but i am getting 5

Comment: n is the number of elements in array

Comment: Can you post your complete code here ?

Comment: Isn't all of this just a single call to [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `n` in your code is the size of the array called `stops`, then you can try to change the condition in the `while` loop to `(currentposition < n && stops[currentposition] <= Value)`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
int index = 0;
int newElement = 400
while (index < n && newElement >= stops[index])
{
    index++;
}
cout<<index-1;
```

Comment: I think you will have to compare the value with the stops[index] not currentposition in line `currentposition >= stops[index]`. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: yeah I was confused what he meant with the currentposition since his question wasn't clear. I think my edited answer would work. what do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to compare the current array value to the value that you are looking for.

```
currentposition = 0;
while (currentposition <= n && stops[currentposition] < value)
{
    ++currentposition;
}
cout << currentposition << ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to traverse the array until you encounter a greater value. So whenever you encounter a greater element than the input value it means the previous element (in the array) was the largest smaller or equal element to the input value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int arr[] = {0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950}, i = 0, val = 400, n = 6;

    while (i < n and arr[i] <= val) {
        i += 1;
    }

    (i >= 1) ? (std::cout << i - 1) : (std::cout << "No element");

}
```

Comment: Just giving the code doesn't solves the problem. A good description should be included too.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is a binary search. Its the most optimized solution as the array is sorted. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

I am providing the solution(code) below:

```
void compute_min_refills(int value, vector<int> stops) {
  // here, s denotes the start of stops
  // and, e denotes the end index of stops
  int s = 0, e = stops.size() - 1;
  // x would contain the index we're searching for
  // by default it is -1
  // if it does not change, it means
  // no such number exists which is less than or equal to value
  int x = -1;
  
  // as long as start is less than or equal end
  while(s <= e) {
    // finding middle index
    int m = (s+e) / 2;
    // check if m index satisfies the condition
    if(stops[m] <= value) {
      x = m;
      // if satisfies, then go forward
      // to check if another greater number
      // is there that satisfies the condition
      s = m + 1;
    } else {
      // if not satisfies, then go backwards
      e = m - 1;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

// now, you can just call compute_min_refills as follows
int x = compute_min_refills(value, stops);
// check if no such number exists
if(x == -1) {
  printf("no such number exists\n");
} else {
  // and print to see the result
  printf("%d\n", stops[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm with reverse iterators

```
int input = 400;
int arr[] = { 0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950 };
auto it = std::find_if(std::rbegin(arr), std::rend(arr), [&input](const int Value) { return Value <= input; });
if (it != std::rend(arr)) {
    std::cout << "Value=" << *it << " with index=" << std::distance(it, std::rend(arr)) - 1 << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Value not found" << std::endl;
}

Output:        
Value=375 with index=2
```

or reverse loop

```
int input = 400;
int arr[] = { 0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950 };
for (auto beg = std::rbegin(arr); beg != std::rend(arr); ++beg)
    if (*beg <= input) {
        std::cout << "Value=" << *beg << " with index=" << (std::rend(arr) - beg - 1) << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    
Output:        
Value=375 with index=2
```

or binary search may be faster on big data

```
int input = 400;
int arr[] = { 0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950 };
auto beg = std::begin(arr);
auto end = std::end(arr);
auto mid = std::begin(arr) + (end - beg) / 2;
while (mid != end && *mid != input) {
    if (input < *mid) {
        end = mid;
    }
    else {
        if (mid + 1 == end || *(mid + 1) > input) {
            break;
        }
        beg = mid + 1;
    }
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
}
if (mid != end) {
    std::cout << "Value=" << *mid << " with index=" << std::distance(std::begin(arr), mid) << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Value not found" << std::endl;
}

Output:        
Value=375 with index=2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of the approach you were trying, you want to reach till the point you can, and once your `value` gets over, you want to print the index till where you have reached.

All the solutions given here works correct, are easy to read and are more efficient. Here I would like to suggest a few things that you can fix in your code and algorithm:

1. You should not loop till `<=n` but till `n-2` as you are checking for next position at line `stops[currentposition + 1]`. The last index of the array is `n-1` and you should not access the element at an index greater than that.
2. You have created a variable `lastposition`, but you aren't updating it in the loop. Also, we don't need a `lastposition` variable, as it will be `currentPosition-1`.
3. I am not sure, but you wanted to check whether you will be able to go to the next position. For the same, you are comparing `stops[currentposition + 1] - stops[lastposition] < Value`. Here what you are trying to do is that with the given amount of fuel left will I be able to go further. But You didn't update the `value` in the loop.

I am attaching the code snippet after fixing few things in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int compute_min_refills(int value, int n, vector<int>  stops){
    int currentposition = 0;
    while(currentposition < (n-1) && stops[currentposition + 1] - stops[currentposition] <= value){ 
        int fuelSpent = stops[currentposition + 1] - stops[currentposition];
        value = value - fuelSpent;
        currentposition = currentposition + 1;
    }
    return currentposition;
}

int main() {
    int  i = 0, val = 1000, n = 6;
    vector<int> vect{0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950}; 
    cout<<compute_min_refills(val,6,vect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Up to now 7 answers. But I am really surprised that nobody provided the standard function for that. For such kind of searches, there is a dedicated function, specifically designed for that purpose: `std::upper_bound`.

Please read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)

This function will return an iterator. If you want to know the index, then simple use `std::distance`. And since we want to have not the greater, but smaller or equal value, we will additionally use `std::prev`

Then, all boils down to a very simple one-liner.

Please see the below example code with some test vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    
    std::vector testValues{0,100,199,200,201,400,949,950,10000};
    
    std::vector data{0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950};
    
    for (const int t : testValues) {
        
        std::cout << t << '\t' << std::distance(data.begin(),std::prev(std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), t)))<< "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The result will be:

```
0       0                                                                                                                                                                   
100     0                                                                                                                                                                   
199     0                                                                                                                                                                   
200     1                                                                                                                                                                   
201     1                                                                                                                                                                   
400     2                                                                                                                                                                   
949     4                                                                                                                                                                   
950     5                                                                                                                                                                   
10000   5
```